# Where to find glass window specs

Tags: windows

Does the AAMA Certification label shown here [image: label image]
<sub>(source: [fayor.com](http://flymike.fayor.com/window_label.gif))</sub>
imply that the window has been subject to wind and projectile testing?
If so, where can I find the details of that testing?

Answer (score 1):

The specifications are in the middle panel of the sticker (with the security standards at the bottom of the right panel.  While it would probably be extremely difficult to get the testing results on the actual window model itself, all of the specs give minimum performance requirements and the certification means that the model passed.

The relevant ones are ANSI/AAMA 101-93 (the DH-C## ones are for double hung condensation resistance), AAMA 1302.5, AAMA 1303.5, ASTM F 588 and ASTM F 842, which cover forced entry resistance.

You can find a pretty good simplified run-down in [this pdf](http://pubstore.aamanet.org/docs/Specifying_Windows_and_Doors_Using_Performance_Standards.pdf).  If you want all the gory details, the full specification is available [here](https://law.resource.org/pub/us/cfr/ibr/001/aama.101-IS2.1997.pdf), but I'm not sure it's the most recent version.